# How to fetch my email and show them in my React APP

Tags: javascript, reactjs, email

I want to add a functionality in my react app, Where the user can ready only the emails for a specific email address. Is there a library or a straight forward API I can use to implement this functionality. Also, if there is any tutorial on how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fetch your email, you first need to create an API from the backend which gets your emails.

If you are meaning to fetch the Gmail APIs, google already gave you the API for you. Please go through the link to know more.
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api